# django-simple-history, saving without historical record not working

Tags: django-simple-history

I am a big fan of django-simple-history, but I do not seem to be able to get "save_without_historical_record" to work properly when I use it inside the default save() method of a model.

I have a model such as this

```
class NzPlasmid (models.Model):
    ...
    plasmid_map = models.FileField("Plasmid Map (max. 2 MB)", upload_to="temp/", blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    ...
```

It has a custom save() method, which renames plasmid_map with the id of the newly created object. In order to do that, I save the object the first time to get its id, then use that to rename plasmid_map. I do not want to save a historical record for the first save, but only for the second. My custom save() method looks like this

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):

    self.skip_history_when_saving = True
    super(NzPlasmid, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

    ... some rename magic here ...

    del self.skip_history_when_saving
    super(NzPlasmid, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

which does not work, as I still get "duplicate" historical records everytime a plasmid is created.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying the `save_model` method in my `admin.py`. When a new plasmid object that has a map is created, generating two historical records due to the renaming of `plasmid_map`, I delete the first one, which contains the "wrong" plasmid_map name, and change the history_type of the second, from changed (~) to created (+):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

    rename_and_preview = False
    new_obj = False

    if obj.pk == None:
        if obj.plasmid_map:
            rename_and_preview = True
            new_obj = True
        obj.save()

        ... some rename magic here ...

        if new_obj:
            obj.history.last().delete()
            history_obj = obj.history.first()
            history_obj.history_type = "+"
            history_obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you save, you're creating the object. However, according to [this line](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/models.py#L353), you can only save without history if the object is being updated, not created. One work around you could try is with a `pre_create_historical_record` signal described [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/advanced.html#using-signals). This is a little hacky, but you could have the signal handling code in your `apps.py` file below:

```
def update_plasmid_map_and_save_instance(sender, instance, history_instance):
    # instance should have id here

    ... some rename magic on your instance model...

    history_instance.plasmid_map = instance.plasmid_map

    instance.save_without_historical_record()


# in apps.py
class TestsConfig(AppConfig):
     def ready(self):
         from ..models import HistoricalNzPlasmid

         pre_create_historical_record.connect(
             update_plasmid_map_and_save_instance,
             sender=HistoricalNzPlasmid,
             dispatch_uid='update_plasmid_map_on_history'
         )
```

And then you won't have to override `save` on `NzPlasmid`. It's a little hacky, but it should work.

Comment: I see! That explains many of the behaviours I am observing. I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NicolaZilio any luck?

Comment: Yes, but I ended up implementing a different solution, which is, I hope, a little less hackerish than what you proposed. See post below